# Can I conditionally render partial views in _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Suppose I have a _Layout.cshtml where I render a left sidebar, which is common to every page of my website.
Something along these lines - a menu, for example

```
<div id="left-sidebar">
    @Html.Action("_MenuView", "LeftSideMenu")
</div>
```

A feature I would like to have would be to add another partial view, but only display it in certain sections of the website.

For example, in the blog section I may want to display a list of post categories or a treeview of the posts.

```
<div id="left-sidebar">
    @Html.Action("_MenuView", "LeftSideMenu")

    @if ("???")
    {
        @Html.Action("_BlogTreeView", "BlogEntries")
    }
</div>
```

How could I do that? I know that I want to display "_BlogTreeView" if the view I'm rendering is returned by BlogController ... where do I go from there?

Comment: Why not to use sections? Create a section in the _layout and implement it in the relevant views

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your layout, add this `section`

```
@RenderSection("blogEntries", false)
```

Then in every view where you want to show the partial view add this:

```
@section blogEntries {
    @Html.Action("_BlogTreeView", "BlogEntries")
}
```